# Did you notice they've fixed the Generalist Badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist

We got a bunch of new inductees, all of them exactly 26 minutes as I write this.

I had wondered why it didn't have anyone yet ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [exact criteria for earning the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/377214) on the global meta, the Generalist badge is only awarded to anyone once each of the top 40 tags is in use on at least 200 questions.

This site didn't cross this threshold until just before you posted this question, and then once it did, followed by a slight delay for badge scripts to run, the badge was awarded for the first time to everyone who qualified for it.

A similar thing also applies for tag badges: badges for a given tag are only awarded once the tag is in use on at least 100 questions, so you may see a bunch of users being awarded a bronze or silver tag badge for the first time once a tag crosses the threshold.